# Is the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}$ equal for all $a \neq 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $a$ be a non-zero real number. Is it true that the value of $$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}$$  is independent on $a$?

Comment: Duplicate [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/43368/6179), so to speak.

Comment: [It was already solved](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/605713/85343) . Just use $\large x = \tan\left(\theta\right)$.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{I}(a)$ denote the integral. Then
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathcal{I}(a) &=& \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)} + \int_1^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{(1+y^2)(1+y^a)} \\
   &\stackrel{y=1/x}{=}&
     \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)} + 
     \int_0^1 \frac{x^a \mathrm{d} x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}   \\
   &=& \int_0^1 \frac{1+x^a}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)} \mathrm{d} x = 
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Thus $\mathcal{I}(a) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ for all $a$. I do not see a need to require $a$ to be non-zero.

Comment: I think there's a typo - you wanted to write $1+x^a$ instead of $1+x^2$ in the numerator. I hope you don't mind correcting. Very nice solution!

Comment: can you explain the second step? thanks

Comment: @tomerg $\mathrm{d}y = -\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$, $\frac{1}{1+y^2} = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, and $\frac{1}{1+y^a}=\frac{x^a}{1+x^a}$. Also notice that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ reverts the orientation, i.e. changes boundaries $1$, $\infty$ into $1$, $0$ respectively. But the negative sign of Jacobian compensates that, thus overall +1 sign.

Comment: +1 Nice argument.  Is there a way to view this in terms of trigonometric identities involving arctangents?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you. Do you mean to perform substitution $u=\tan(x)$, so that $\mathcal{I}(a) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \left( 1 + \tan^a(u) \right)^{-1} \mathrm{d} u$ ? The idea of the proof will then remain much the same, split integration into $(0,\pi/4)$ and $(\pi/4, \pi/2)$ and use $u \mapsto \pi/2-u$ substitution for the second integral. Then due to $\tan(\pi/2-u)  = \cot(u)$ the result would follow.

Comment: How does the numerator after the substitution become $x^a$? I would have expected $x^{2+a}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Please see my response to tomerg 4 comments above.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: perhaps [Anamitra's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/87999/) might satisfy your request re: trigonometric identities.

Comment: This is related to an integral challenge problem I made up: Show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(a^{2}+1\right)}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{a}\right)\left(1+a^{2}\right)}dxda=\pi^2 \log 2.$$  Although, the problem is not so tricky now that you know the first step!!  Without knowing that, it can be unclear how one should proceed.

Answer (score 34):

With a change of variable
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}\overset{x\to1/x}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}
$$
Adding and dividing by two yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I was just about to post this when I saw Sasha's answer appear so I deleted it. However, now that Sasha has probably capped for the day, I decided to undelete it.

Comment: This is the simplest answer IMO. I upvoted this. :-)

Comment: How does the numerator after the substitution become $x^a$? I would have expected $x^{2+a}$.

Comment: @Henning: 

$$\begin{align}\int_\infty^0\frac{\mathrm{d}\frac{1}{x}}{\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\right)\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^a\right)}&=\int_\infty^0\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}\;\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)/x^2\;(1+x^a)/x^a}\\&=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a\; \mathrm{d}x }{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}\end{align}$$ I believe that is correct.

Comment: Oh, of course. $ $

Answer (score 14):

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}$

Substitution:

$\displaystyle x=\tan\theta$

$\displaystyle dx=\sec^2\theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+\tan^a \theta}$

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^a \theta d\theta}{\sin^a \theta + \cos^a \theta}$

$\displaystyle  I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^a(\pi/2-\theta) d\theta}{\sin^{a}(\pi/2-\theta) + \cos^a (\pi/2-\theta)}$

$\displaystyle I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^a\theta d\theta}{\sin^a\theta + \cos^a \theta}$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle 2I=\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta$

$\displaystyle I=\pi/4$

Comment: Excellent! I think this should satisfy [Michael Hardy's request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87735/is-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-mathrmd-x1x21xa-equal-for-a/87740#comment206706_87740).

Comment: Nice argument. +1

Answer (score 13):

$$
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)}\\
\frac{dI}{da} & = -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a \log(x) dx}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)^2}
\end{align}
$$

Let $\displaystyle J = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a \log(x) dx}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)^2}$
$$
\begin{align}
J & = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a \log(x) dx}{(1+x^2)(1+x^a)^2}\\
& \stackrel{x=1/y}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1/y^a \log(1/y) d(1/y)}{(1+(1/y)^2)(1+(1/y)^a)^2}\\
& = \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{y^a \log(y) dy}{(1+y^2)(1+y^a)^2}\\
& = -J
\end{align}
$$

Hence, $\frac{dI}{da}=0$. Hence, $I$ is independent of $a$.