# Hard integral, low hints...

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{ - \pi /2}^{\pi /2} \frac1{2007^{x} + 1}\cdot \frac {\sin^{2008}x}{\sin^{2008}x + \cos^{2008}x} \, dx .$$

This integral stuns me for a while, I just can't solve it! I tried integration by recurrence since here it seems that we have something that looks like a recurrence, but nothing comes up. I also tried **all** the integration techniques I'm aware of but they just don't work.

So I fear like this integral uses something like Fourier, or some Laplace transform thing or something of that sort but I don't know them.

That's why I will be very thankful if they could explain me how to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Something very similar has already been solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608067/int-pi-2-pi-2-frac-sin2012x-left1-alphax-right-left-sin). You should be able to modify that answer to give you your answer!

Comment: How can we extend that to the case$^{2008}$

Comment: Read the answer: it turns out the value of your integral is insensitive to the precise value $2008$ (it depends only on $2007$ in the $2007^x$ term). [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx/605713#605713) answer might also be useful to prove this.

Comment: I see how to do it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this way to do. Let
$$ I=\int_{ - \pi /2}^{\pi /2} \frac1{2007^{x} + 1}\cdot \frac {\sin^{2008}x}{\sin^{2008}x + \cos^{2008}x} \, dx.\tag{1}$$
Now use the substitution $x=-u$ to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
I&=&-\int_{\pi /2}^{-\pi /2} \frac1{2007^{-u} + 1}\cdot \frac {\sin^{2008}(-u)}{\sin^{2008}(-u) + \cos^{2008}(-u)} \, (-du)\\
&=&\int_{-\pi /2}^{\pi /2} \frac{2007^u}{2007^{u} + 1}\cdot \frac {\sin^{2008}u}{\sin^{2008}u + \cos^{2008}u} \, dx.\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
So adding (1) and (2) will give
$$ 2I=\int_{- \pi/2}^{\pi /2}\frac {\sin^{2008}x}{\sin^{2008}x + \cos^{2008}x} \, dx$$
or
$$ I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{- \pi/2}^{\pi /2}\frac {\sin^{2008}x}{\sin^{2008}x + \cos^{2008}x} \, dx=\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\frac {\sin^{2008}x}{\sin^{2008}x + \cos^{2008}x} \, dx.\tag{3}$$
Now use the substitution $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ to get
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\pi /2}\frac {\cos^{2008}u}{\sin^{2008}u + \cos^{2008}u} \, du.\tag{4}$$
Now adding (3) and (4) will give you $ 2I=\pi/2$ or $I=\pi/4$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this trick. How did you learn it, and in general how to learn integration tricks like this one? I can't imagine myself ever have to invent something like this.

Comment: @user165134, this trick is very common for some integrals which have some symmetrical properties.

Comment: ah! How to learn more tricks?

Comment: @user165134, work on more problems.

Comment: I mean for example this integration technique you used in your problem I would never have thought of it, then how could I ever learn something if I can never find it?

Comment: @user165134 A bit note:
$$
\int_{-\Large\frac\pi2}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}\ dx=2\int_{0}^{\Large\frac\pi2}\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin^nx+\cos^nx}\ dx
$$
is only valid for $n$ is **even integer**. +1 anyway.