# Looking for Comprehensive Integration Techniques Tutorial

Tags: integration, learning, online-resources

I am trying to improve my skills and I usually learn best by attempting problems just barely above my skill level then reading the solution. Does anyone know where I can find structured integration problems that introduce various techniques? If anyone knows about Project Euler or Brilliant that is the kind of thing I am looking for, but focused on more advanced integration techniques like beta functions or residues.

Comment: http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com

Comment: I do know about that site, but it does not seem very active -- the tutorials board has only 9 threads. Also I am looking for something more structured for learning so that I am given good problems to solve with solutions if I am stuck, instead of spending time sorting through problems to find good ones then posting to get help.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871292) question.