# Hard definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos^{2008} (x)}{\sin^{2008} (x)+\cos^{2008} (x)}~dx$$

I hope anyone can answer this definite integral.

Comment: This was most likely a contest problem from 2008 lol

Comment: As a general rule, when you see a number like 2008 in a question, it's a good clue that the number isn't important. For cosines and sines, all that usually matters is whether the exponent is odd or even - so try replacing all of the 2008's with 2's, and see if you can solve it. Then try it with 4 or 6, and see if you see a pattern you can use for 2008.

Comment: It was 1/(1+tan^2008 x). I managed to make it in this way.(i donot know any more)

Comment: Same way as: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305511/solve-trigonometric-integral-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac-sin2014x-sin20

Comment: $\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x=u$

Comment: Alternatively, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Haha, 2008 is actually a hint, since this number is insanely large for any serious manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Enforcing the substitution $x\to \pi/2-x$ yields

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{2008}(x)}{\cos^{2008}(x)+\sin^{2008}(x)}\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^{2008}(x)}{\cos^{2008}(x)+\sin^{2008}(x)}\,dx$$

Hence,

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{2008}(x)}{\cos^{2008}(x)+\sin^{2008}(x)}\,dx=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{2008}(x)+\sin^{2008}(x)}{\cos^{2008}(x)+\sin^{2008}(x)}\,dx=\pi/4$$

Comment: Don't you also have to transform the limits, then employ the fact that the function is even?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Yes, but not that $dx\to -dx$ and the minus sign flips the new limits $\pi/2$ to $0$ back to $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint...substitute $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ and you get the same integral but with $\sin$ in the numerator. So $2I=$?