# Integral independent of the parameter? $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^a)(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My claim is that:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^a)(1+x)^2}dx=\frac12$$
regardless of the value of $a$. A couple examples are [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%291%2BPower%5Bt%2C-1.43%5D%5C%2841%29Power%5B%5C%2840%291%2Bt%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2Cinf%7D%5D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%291%2BPower%5Bt%2C32%5D%5C%2841%29Power%5B%5C%2840%291%2Bt%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2Cinf%7D%5D).

I came across this result while searching cool integrals to evaluate, but I could not tame this one. I know a similar result, that you can find [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1339636/1174256). It states that:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^a)(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
and it is proved using the substitution $x=\tan u$, however using the same substitution in my integral seems to be pointless. How should one proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^a)(1+x)^2}\overset{x\to\frac1x}{dx}\\
=& \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^{-a})(1+x)^2}dx\\
=& \ \frac12 \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}
\left( \frac{1}{1+x^{a}}+\frac{1}{1+x^{-a}} \right)dx\\
=&\ \frac12 \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx=\frac12
\end{align}

Comment: I tried differentiating the integral w.r.t. $a$, and since the integral is just a constant, is should give $0$. But it does not. Why is this the case?

Comment: @Zima - It is zero, as shown below. $$I’(a)=-\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x^{a/2}+x^{-a/2})^2(1+x)^2}dx=0$$

Comment: but derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^c}$ w.r.t. c is $-\frac{x^c\log x}{(1+x^c)^2}$, and when you integrate together with $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is not $0$

Comment: @Zima - Note that $\frac{x^a}{(1+x^a)^2}= \frac1{(x^{a/2}+ x^{-a/2})^2}$, which leads to $I’(a)=0$ as stated in above comment.