# Calculate the Integral $\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\sin^{7/2}x}{\sin^{7/2}x+\cos^{7/2}x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have to calculate this Integral -

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\sin^{7/2}x}{\sin^{7/2}x+\cos^{7/2}x}dx$$

I have no idea how to start,
Hint someone ?
Thanks.

Comment: This one occurs every now and then. If you do $u=\pi/2-x$ you get the same integral but with $\cos$ instead of $\sin$ in the numerator. Add them and you get the integral of the function $1$. This should be a duplicate, but the $7/2$ can be changed to more or less whatever, so it is not so easy to find the other ones...

Comment: How will you get the integral of $1$ ?

Comment: @Noam $$\frac{s}{s+c} + \frac{c}{s+c} = 1$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx/605713#605713

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:
$$\int_a^{b} f(x) \, dx = \int_a^{b} f(a+b-x) \, dx$$
This property can be proven easily by substituting $a+b-x=t$.

Now consider $f(x)=\frac{\sin^{7/2}x}{\sin^{7/2}x+\cos^{7/2}x}$ and $a=0$, $b=\pi/2$, to get
$$I=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\sin^{7/2}x}{\sin^{7/2}x+\cos^{7/2}x}dx=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\sin^{7/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}{\sin^{7/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)+\cos^{7/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}dx.$$
Thus we have 
\begin{align*}
I & = \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\sin^{7/2}x}{\sin^{7/2}x+\cos^{7/2}x}dx\\
\text{and also }\\
I & = \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\sin^{7/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}{\sin^{7/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)+\cos^{7/2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}dx= \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\cos^{7/2}x}{\cos^{7/2}x+\sin^{7/2}x}dx.
\end{align*}
Adding the two to get
$$2I=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{\sin^{7/2}x+\cos^{7/2}x}{\sin^{7/2}x+\cos^{7/2}x}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1 \, dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Thus $I=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

NOTE: as indicated in one of the comments, $7/2$ has no significance, it could have been replaced by another suitable exponent and still the answer would be the same.

Comment: Ok,Thanks.
But, Why $\int_a^{b} f(x) \, dx = \int_a^{b} f(a+b-x) \, dx$ ?

Comment: @Noam if you read my solution, I have also given the hint of proving it by using the substitution $a+b-x=t$.

Comment: @Noam using $a+b-x=t$, you can have $\frac{dx}{dt}=-1$ and for the limits when $x=a$, then $t=b$, when $x=b$, then $t=a$. With this $\int_a^bf(a+b-x) , dx=-\int_b^a f(t) dt=\int_a^b f(t) \, dt.$

Comment: If i use substitution, I will get.
$\int _0^{\frac{\pi \:}{2}}\:\frac{\sin ^{7/2}x}{\sin ^{7/2}x+\cos ^{7/2}x}dx\:=\:-\:\int _0^{\frac{\pi \:\:}{2}}\:\frac{cos\:^{7/2}t}{cos\:^{7/2}t+sin\:^{7/2}t}dt$

Comment: @Noam there will be no negative sign because the limits will be reversed.

Comment: Ok,So -
$\int _0^{\frac{\pi \:}{2}}\:\frac{\sin ^{7/2}x}{\sin ^{7/2}x+\cos ^{7/2}x}dx\:=\:\:\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^0\:\frac{cos\:^{7/2}t}{cos\:^{7/2}t+sin\:^{7/2}t}dt$

But then(If the limits are reversed), How can i adding them together ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34569/discussion-between-noam-and-anurag-a).