# Two complex definite Integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to solve these Integrals

1.

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt {2}}x} dx$$

2.
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2}$$
Thanks

Comment: For the first see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: for 2) try the half angle substitution

Comment: for 2) MMA says $\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \pi }{4\ 2^{3/4}}$

Comment: @Mani Indeed you asked two questions  whereas you accepted  one of them

Comment: I have an alternative solution to 2 but now I can't post it because someone marked it off topic.....

Comment: When are we going to stop answering multiple questions posted as one? It's harmful for this site. Such questions need to be separated

Comment: Jack Lam would you like to explain your alternate Solution., Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt{2}}x}dx.....(1)$$

Using $$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$$

So $$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\cot^{\sqrt{2}}x}dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan ^{\sqrt{2}}x}{1+\tan^{\sqrt{2}}x}dx....(2)$$

Now Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$

So we get $$2I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1\cdot dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow I = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

For the second integral:

Substitute $t=\tan{x}$ in order to get:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2} dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(\sqrt{2}+t^2)^2}dt.$$
Observe that $$d(-\frac{t}{t^2+\sqrt{2}})=\frac{t^2-\sqrt{2}}{(t^2+\sqrt{2})^2}.$$
Now write $t^2+1$ as the following sum: $$a(t^2+\sqrt{2})+b(t^2-\sqrt{2}).$$ It is easy to calculate that $\boxed{a=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}}$ and $\boxed{b=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}}$, from the system of equations $$a+b=1,$$ $$a-b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
Using the previous, we get 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(\sqrt{2}+t^2)^2}dt=a\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+t^2}dt+b\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2-\sqrt{2}}{(\sqrt{2}+t^2)^2}dt,$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(\sqrt{2}+t^2)^2}dt=a\frac{\arctan{\frac{t}{\sqrt[4]{2}}}}{\sqrt[4]{2}}|_0^\infty-b\frac{t}{t^2+\sqrt{2}}|_0^\infty,$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(\sqrt{2}+t^2)^2}dt=a\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sqrt[4]{2}},$$
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(\sqrt{2}+t^2)^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{4\sqrt{2}}\frac{\pi}{\sqrt[4]{2}}.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Set 
$$I(a,b,n)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x)^n}dx$$
$$\frac{\partial I(a,b,n)}{\partial a}=-n\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2x}{(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x)^{n+1}}dx$$
$$\frac{\partial I(a,b,n)}{\partial b}=-n\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2x}{(a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x)^{n+1}}dx$$
Therefore
$$\frac{\partial I(a,b,n)}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial I(a,b,n)}{\partial b}=-nI(a,b,n+1)$$
we have

$$I(a,b,n+1)=-\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\partial I(a,b,n)}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial I(a,b,n)}{\partial b}\right)\tag 1$$
Now we should compute $I(a,b,1)$ 
$$I(a,b,1)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1+\tan^2x}{a+b\tan^2x}dx$$
Set $u= \tan x$, thus
$$I(a,b,1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a+bu^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{ab}}$$
so
$$\frac{\partial I(a,b,1)}{\partial a}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{b}}{4a\sqrt{a}\,b}$$
similarly
$$\frac{\partial I(a,b,1)}{\partial b}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{a}}{4b\sqrt{b}\,a}$$
apply $(1)$
$$I(a,b,2)=-\left(\frac{\partial I(a,b,1)}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial I(a,b,1)}{\partial b}\right)=\frac{\pi(a+b)}{4ab\sqrt{ab}}$$
set $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1$, finally

> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dx}{(\sqrt{2}\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2}=\frac{\pi(1+\sqrt{2})}{4\sqrt[4]{8}}$$