# MIT Integration Bee $21$

Tags: integration

**Question:**

$$\int_0^\infty {{1}\over{(1+x^{2015})({1+x^2}})}dx$$

How to solve these integrals. I have no idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$:

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty {{1}\over{(1+x^{2015})({1+x^2}})}dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty {{1}\over{(1+x^{-2015})({1+x^{-2}}})} \frac{1}{x^2}dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty {{x^{2015}}\over{(1+x^{2015})({1+x^{2}}})} dx
\end{align*}

Then,

\begin{align*}
2I &= \int_0^\infty {{1}\over{(1+x^{2015})({1+x^2}})}dx+\int_0^\infty {{x^{2015}}\over{(1+x^{2015})({1+x^2}})}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty {{1+x^{2015}}\over{(1+x^{2015})({1+x^2}})}dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}

So $I=\pi/4$.

Comment: Great work bro.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer, set $x=\tan y$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx     or  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856

Comment: How can you substitute x with 1/x ? Shouldn't you use a different parameter.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer $x$ is a dummy variable. If you wish, the substitution could be $x=1/u$, then you change $u$ to $x$ later to make the $2I$ formulation.

Comment: @Argon OK got it.

Comment: @Argon hey I not not being allowed to ask anymore questions,can you state me the reason even though I have contributed so much useful stuff in the community.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer I wouldn't know. Best thing would be to contact a moderator on chat.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer: you have been blocked from asking questions from an automated script, since your last five/six questions attracted a negative score before being deleted. A moderator cannot remove such block, but positive contributions through answers should remove it pretty fast.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ok from now on I will contribute to the community positively and not post anything which goes against the community rules.