# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^m)(1+x^2)}\,dx$

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

I saw somewhere that the above integral is equal to $\pi/4$ for all real number $m$.

This seems to be surprising. Does anyone have a nice proof?

Comment: This should not be surprising: let $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ and you will get the same integral with an extra factor of $x^m$. Add both and you've gotten rid of $m$.

Answer (score 10):

Let

$$\begin{align}
I(m) &= \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^m)(1+x^2)}\tag{$x = t^{-1}$}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{-2}\,dt}{(1+t^{-m})(1+t^{-2})}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{(1+t^{-m})(1+t^2)}\\
&= I(-m).
\end{align}$$

But

$$\begin{align}
I(m) + I(-m) &= \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+x^m} + \frac{1}{1+x^{-m}}\right)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+x^m} + \frac{x^m}{1+x^{m}}\right)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Beat me to it :-) (+1)

Comment: You typed too slowly [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396170/integrate-int-0-infty-frac-log-1x1x2dx), it seems.

Comment: Yeah, I had to look up the prior post. I believe that this question is a duplicate, however.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me. But I have no idea what terms to search for to find a duplicate. If you do, go ahead.

Comment: Found it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/87735), and my answer is the same as yours :-)