# Computing $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}$

Tags: integration

> How can I compute $$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}\quad?$$

**My attempt:** Looking at the limits of the integration I see that we should induce some $\tan^{-1}(x)$ so if we put $\infty$ we would get something like $\frac{\pi}{2}$ . But I am not sure how to proceed . Partial fractions don't yield good integral.

Comment: Are you familiar with (complex) contour integration, or would that be outside your level of experience?

Comment: No I am not familiar with it I am just in grade 12 so if there is an elementary way like summation of some series /expansion it would be better for me

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/87735

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For any $a > 0$, consider the integral

$$\mathcal{I} = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^a} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Change variable to $y = \frac1x$, we have

$$\mathcal{I} = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+y^{-a}}\frac{1}{1+y^{-2}} \frac{dy}{y^2}
= \int_0^\infty \frac{y^a}{1+y^a}\frac{dy}{1+y^2}$$

Summing the two expression of $\mathcal{I}$ and divide by $2$, we get

$$\mathcal{I} = \frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
independent of value of $a$.

---

**Random Notes**

About the question how do I arrive this answer, the key is symmetry.

When one is facing a complicated looking integral, the first thing one should do is looking for symmetry hidden in the integral.

For the integral at hand, the integrand has similar form and the range of integration is invariant under a change of variable from $x$ to $\frac1x$.
In this case, there are a few things one should check.

1. Do different part of integral cancel each other?
2. Can the original and transformed integral combined together to something simpler?
3. Will changing variable to $y = x \pm \frac{\text{const}}{x}$ reduces the integrand to a more manageable form.

It turns out the second strategy works and the rest is mostly following your nose.

Comment: Just like mine earlier. ;-))

Comment: Cute. Were the clues from the limits all you needed to spot this change of variables?

Comment: @morganrogers The success of the methodology  requires more than the limits extending from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's any way to see that the integral given by the  derivative $dI/da$ is identically zero.

Comment: Clearly that is true, but when evaluating definite integrals, the procedure is (as here) 'spot the trick and follow through'. You had to notice that the substitution given was potentially useful and then mess around a bit; I was wondering how you spotted it in the first place.

Comment: @MorganRogers it is not the limits but rather the symmetry of the integrand. if you see an integrand who has similar form under change of variable $x \to \frac1x$, There are several things one should try and see whether it simplify the expression 1) Can they be combined together and 2)  changing variable to $y = x \pm \frac{\text{const}}{x}$.

Comment: @morganrogers I was able to discern quickly that the "trick" would be successful because of experience with integrals of similar attributes.  And now you are equipped with this tool you can employ the next time you encounter an integral for which this tool is suited.  -Mark

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking for myself! It would be helpful to include in an answer how you worked out to do what you did. This means that people can refer to this answer in future to answer similar enough problems.

Answer (score 11):

HINT:

Enforce the substitution $x\to 1/x$ and combine the results.

SPOILER ALERT:  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.

> Enforcing the substitution $x\to 1/x$ reveals $$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}\,dx\\\\&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2015}}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}\,dx\tag 1\end{align}$$Adding the right-hand and left-hand sides of $(1)$ and dividing by $2$ yields $$I=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\pi/4$$

Comment: +1. This is similar to a 'popular one' in MSE: $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm{d}x \over 1 + \tan^{\,\mu}\left(\, x\, \right)}}$.

Comment: @felixmarin Thank you.  And yes, you're right.  Evaluating the integral you mentioned is facilitated by enforcing the substitution $x\to \pi/2 -x$.  Then combining reduces to a trivial integral.  It is indeed similar in kind.  +1 for your very useful comment.  -Mark

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.