# Find the integral $\int_{0}^\infty \frac {1}{(x^2+1)(x^7+1)} \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How i should deal with it, i’ve tried fraction decomposition, but haven’t worked so far.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\frac 1n}^n \frac {1}{(x^2+1)(x^7+1)} \, dx$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch my bad, that’s right. I ve edited.

Comment: The answer is $\frac\pi4$ as is proven here: [Computing $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885291/computing-int-0-infty-frac11x20151x2)

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks.

Comment: The substitution $x=\tan\theta$ also works here.