# Evaluate $\int_\frac12 ^2 \frac1x\tan(x-\frac1x)dx $

Tags: integration

$$\int\limits_\frac{1}{2} ^2 \frac{1}{x}\tan\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

I have tried substitution and by parts and it seems failed at all. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: "I have tried substitution" Have you? Which substitution(s)?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87735/is-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-mathrmd-x1x21xa-equal-for-a

Comment: @monhawk Why `\int\limits` in a displayed equation? To eat more vertical space than necessary?

Answer (score 13):

$$I = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\frac{1}{x}\tan\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)dx = \int_{2}^{\frac{1}{2}}u\cdot \frac{-1}{u^2}\tan\left(\frac{1}{u}-u\right)du = -\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\frac{1}{u}\tan\left(u - \frac{1}{u}\right)du = -I$$
Where the second step was obtained by letting $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{u}, dx = \frac{-1}{u^2}du$.

Since $I = -I$, we have $I = 0$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $$I = \int_{1/2}^{2}\frac{1}{x}\tan \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$

Put $x=e^t$, then $t=\ln(x)$ and $dx=e^t\,dt$ hence, changing limits, we get $$I = \int_{-\ln(2)}^{\ln(2)}\underbrace{\tan\left(e^{t}-e^{-t}\right)}_{\bf{Odd\; function}}dt = 0$$

Comment: +1. A nice alternative to the change of variable approach.

Comment: Did you mean $dt=\frac{dx}{x}$? I am under the impression $dx=dt$ is not only false, but results in a missing term in the $t$ integral, since $\frac1x$ has no matching $t$ term.

Comment: MicG I have edited it.

Comment: @juantheron I must ask, how have you thought about this substitution?

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ I = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}\frac{1}{x}\cdot \tan \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx$$

Now Let $\displaystyle\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) = t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx = dt\Rightarrow \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx = x\,dt$

and Changing Limits

Now Using $$ \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 -\left(x-\frac{1}{x} \right)^2 = 4\Rightarrow \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+4}=\sqrt{t^2+4}$$

So Integral $$ I = \int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\tan t\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}\cdot \frac{x}{x} \, dt = \int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}\tan t\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}} \, dt$$

So we get $$ I = \int_{-\frac{3}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}} \underbrace{\frac{\tan t}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}}_{\textbf{odd function}} \, dt = 0$$

Above we have used the formula $$\displaystyle \int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = 0\;,$$ If $f(x)$ is odd function.